# Convert hexadecimal color to integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm trying to convert a hexadecimal color string to a int in javascript.

The color int must be the same format as VB6. I think the bytes are not in the normal order. Ex: 255 is red (#ff0000) and 16776960 is Aqua (#00ffff)

I have a function to do the inverse: (But someone in the comments told me that it's not correct)

```
function VBColorToHEX(i) {
    var hex = (i & 0xFF).toString(16) +
              ((i >> 8) & 0xFF).toString(16) +
            ((i >> 16) & 0xFF).toString(16) +
            ((i >> 24) & 0xFF).toString(16);

    hex += '000000';
    hex = hex.substring(0, 6);
    return "#" + hex;
}
```

But was unable to write a function to return to my initial value.

Can you help me?

**EDIT:**

I corrected my original function by padding each separate colors:

```
function VBColorToHEX(i) {
   var r = (i & 0xFF).toString(16);
   var g = ((i >> 8) & 0xFF).toString(16);
   var b = ((i >> 16) & 0xFF).toString(16);

   r = ('0' + r).slice(-2);
   g = ('0' + g).slice(-2);
   b = ('0' + b).slice(-2);

   return "#" + r + g + b;
}
```

Comment: Get VB6 to tell you the color number for pure red, green, and blue.  Then it should be obvious which bytes you need.

Comment: For anyone wondering the VB6 color format is `&H00BBGGRR&`

Comment: I don't think your function VBColorToHEX is correct.  VBColorToHEX(1) returns #100000 but it seems like it should return #010000.

Comment: The colors look correct, but as you say,certain value can be wrong. Which changes should I made?

Comment: Would you just like to pick an Hex like 0xFF and get the associated Int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working version of your original function, which I think will make more sense to you about how it actually works.

```
function VBColorToHEX(i) {
    var bbggrr =  ("000000" + i.toString(16)).slice(-6);
    var rrggbb = bbggrr.substr(4, 2) + bbggrr.substr(2, 2) + bbggrr.substr(0, 2);
    return "#" + rrggbb;
}
```

Then, to do the reverse, do this:

```
function HEXToVBColor(rrggbb) {
    var bbggrr = rrggbb.substr(4, 2) + rrggbb.substr(2, 2) + rrggbb.substr(0, 2);
    return parseInt(bbggrr, 16);
}
```

Comment: Your version of VBColorToHEX does't work, the color produced are very different than those set in my VB application.

Comment: @Xasun, I'm not sure why you say that, as it works fine for the two examples you gave "255 is red (#ff0000) and 16776960 is Aqua (#00ffff)".  Can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: My bad, I tested your function with "255" in string by error. Your solution work­.

Answer (score 1):

```
function VBColorToHEX(i) {
    var hex = (i & 0xFF).toString(16) +
              ((i >> 8) & 0xFF).toString(16) +
            ((i >> 16) & 0xFF).toString(16) +
            ((i >> 24) & 0xFF).toString(16);

    hex += '000000'; // pad result
    hex = hex.substring(0, 6);
    return "#" + hex;
}
```

You're padding the result with zeroes instead of padding each color value.
For instance if i = 657930, the string hex value is something like #0A0A0A but you'll output #AAA000 instead.

Beside, if you're extracting 4 color channels you need 8 chars and not 6.

PS for the padding, see for instance [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460414/5695504).