# Convert a hex color into a int32 value with js

Tags: javascript, hex

I have this value: -16744448;
And this value is this color: [image: the color associated with -16744448]

And now, I need to know how to change any value in hex like
`'#01ff00', '#7fff82', '#c1ffc0', '#16F6F5','#81FFFC','#BFFFFF'`
to int32 (is necessary)

```
function toColor(num) {
    num >>>= 0;
    var b = num & 0xFF,
        g = (num & 0xFF00) >>> 8,
        r = (num & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
        a = ( (num & 0xFF000000) >>> 24 ) / 255 ;
    return "rgba(" + [r, g, b, a].join(",") + ")";
}
```

I used this formula, but I don't know how to apply reverse engineering.

EDIT:

I have this value: -16744448 in the database, with the formula i have this value for the color: '#008000', i need to convert this color again in -16744448.

**When i used the formula mentioned in the comments i got: 32768**

This value is from VB.net, this function: [Color.FromArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hexadecimal color to integer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466604/convert-hexadecimal-color-to-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no such thing as "int32" in JavaScript. You can convert the string to a number.

Comment: Yeah, i know, but in the database i got only 'int32' numbers from Visual Basic. And know i need to transform these colors. They get with color.toARGB

Comment: @RyanWilson that answer doesn't work... He used a rgb color.

Comment: I don't know about the `a` - it doesn't seem to be in your number.
"32768" is correct, just subtract 16^6.

Comment: `"#"+("0".repeat(6)+(Math.pow(16,6)-16744448).toString(16)).slice(-6)` gives `"#008000"`. `parseInt("#008000".slice(-6),16)-Math.pow(16,6)` gives -`16744448`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're removing the "#", parsing from hexadecimal to decimal, complementing by 16^6.
Back:
Uncomplementing, to hexadecimal string fill with leading zeros, trimming to last 6, adding "#" at the beginning.

```js
var values=["#008000",'#01ff00', '#7fff82', '#c1ffc0', '#16F6F5','#81FFFC','#BFFFFF'];

values.forEach(v=>{
  var r=parseInt(v.slice(-6),16)-Math.pow(16,6);
  var rr="#"+("0".repeat(6)+(Math.pow(16,6)+r).toString(16)).slice(-6);
  console.log(v,r,rr);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! that was exacty i want

Comment: Glad to help!
Thanks for accepting my answer - could you up-vote it as well, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a hexadecimal code value with `parseInt`. Just set the radix to `16`. This even takes care of three-digit hex code like `#F00`.

I started writing a [CSS color value parser](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/chx035qd/) a while back, and used my hex logic below.

```js
const colors = [ '#01ff00', '#7fff82', '#c1ffc0', '#16F6F5','#81FFFC','#BFFFFF' ]

console.log(colors.map(color => toColor(hexToInt(color))));

function hexToInt(input) {
  return parseInt(input.replace(/^#([\da-f])([\da-f])([\da-f])$/i,
    '#$1$1$2$2$3$3').substring(1), 16);
}; 

function toColor(num) {
    num >>>= 0;
    const b = num & 0xFF,
          g = (num & 0xFF00) >>> 8,
          r = (num & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
          a = ( (num & 0xFF000000) >>> 24 ) / 255 ;
    return "rgba(" + [r, g, b, a].join(",") + ")";
}
```