# Discord.js get current message embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make my bot's embed color update dynamically (using random color, editing HSV value). However, using `msg.embeds[0]` seems to give me the *previous* shown embed.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
collector.on('end', () => {
    currentEmbed = msg.embeds[0]
    const rowAgain = msg.components[0]

    for (c of rowAgain.components) {
        c.disabled = true;
    }

    let colorHex = `#${vb2Hex(currentEmbed.color)}`;
    const colorHsv = hex.hsv(colorHex);
    const val = colorHsv[2] - 5;

    colorHsv.splice(2, 1, val);
    colorHex = hsv.hex(colorHsv);
    color = parseInt(colorHex, 16);

    currentEmbed.color = color;
    msg.edit({ embeds: [currentEmbed], components: [row] });
});
```

I'm using the `color-convert` library and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467449/11690210) script (minus the `substr()`) to edit the colors. I'm still new-ish to bots, so I might've missed something. How can I fix/improve it? I'll gladly share more info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, had to put `msg =` in front of `msg.edit()` during an interaction to keep it up to date.

```
await i.deferUpdate();
await wait(0);
msg = await msg.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
```